# In HLSL script, why does random function produce negative values?

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl

I'm currently learning shader scripting with Unity HLSL language and this awesome resource: https://thebookofshaders.com

I created my random method and a zeroOrOne method which just return 0 or 1 according to a given and the worlposition

```
const static float randomMultiplier = 43758.5453123f;
const static float2 randomDotVector = float2(12.9898f,78.233f);

float random2d (float2 st) {
    return frac(sin(dot(st, randomDotVector)) * randomMultiplier);
}

float zeroOrOne (float probability, float2 pos) {
    float r = random2d(pos);
    return saturate(sign(probability-r));
}
```

In order to chase down little bug, I simplified my zeroOrOne method to:

```
float zeroOrOne (float probability, float2 pos) {
    float r = random2d(pos);
    return sign(r + 0.001f);
}
```

And here's what I can observe :

[image: rendered image]

What I understand is: if some pixels remain black, the result of `sign(r + 0.001f)` is 0, or -1.
This means that r can be less or equal to 0.001. But r should be a `frac` of a sin, and `frac` is between 0 and 1!!

Is there some floating point black magic here?

Does it depends of the device architecture? (I'm on a macbook, no graphic card)

Does I miss something?

**EDIT**: I forced the random value to be positive only, and the strange pixels remains...

Here's the code, simplified to minimum.
https://gist.github.com/martinprot/f3071b6036ae9b72f17ef941c4734a48

**EDIT**: I tried on another computer, with a real CG. The bug does not occur on this machine!